# Datatables editor not sending ID

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I need to update data in mysql and I am using datatables inline edit extension.
The problem I need to solve is, how can I send the id of the row, the name of the field and the value of the cell. 
This is the data that it sends;
I get:

```
 data[undefined][player_nickname]:Leon
```

but I need:

```
data[1][player_nickname]:Rafantunessdds
```

This my js code:

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        table: "#dtables",
        ajax: {
            edit: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>players/saveUserData'
            },
        },
        fields: [{
                label: "Nickname:",
                name: "player_nickname"
            }, {
                label: "Email:",
                name: "player_email"
            }, {
                label: "Password:",
                name: "player_password"
            },
            {
                label: "Is Admin:",
                name: "is_admin"
            },
            {
                label: "Is Moderator:",
                name: "is_moderator"
            },
            {
                label: "is Manager:",
                name: "is_manager"
            },
            {
                label: "is Premiun:",
                name: "player_premium"
            },
            {
                label: "Is banned:",
                name: "player_banned"
            },
        ]
    });
```

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        ajax: "players/saveuserdata.php",
        table: ".dtables",
        fields: [{
                label: "Nickname:",
                name: "player_nickname"
            }, {
                label: "Email:",
                name: "player_email"
            }, {
                label: "Password:",
                name: "player_password"
            },
            {
                label: "Is Admin:",
                name: "is_admin"
            },
            {
                label: "Is Moderator:",
                name: "is_moderator"
            },
            {
                label: "is Manager:",
                name: "is_manager"
            },
            {
                label: "is Premiun:",
                name: "player_premium"
            },
            {
                label: "Is banned:",
                name: "player_banned"
            },
        ]
    });

    $('.dtables').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        editor.inline(this);
    });
    $('.dtables').DataTable({

        data: <?php echo($players) ?>,
        columns: [
            {data: 'player_id'},
            {data: 'player_nickname'},
            {data: 'player_email'},
            {data: 'player_password'},
            {data: 'is_admin'},
            {data: 'is_moderator'},
            {data: 'is_manager'},
            {data: 'player_premium'},
            {data: 'player_banned'}

        ]
    });
```

How can I send the id of the row?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`idSrc`](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/option/idSrc) JSON property  rom which to read / write the row's ID property.

```
idSrc: "player_id"
```